# Equivalence of points on a smooth cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2 (\mathbb{C})$ be a smooth cubic. Show that $(p)$~$(q)$ if and only if $p=q$.

$p$ and $q$ are points, and two divisors $D$ and $D'$ are ~ if $D-D' = (f)$ for some meromorphic function $f$. I have to show there is no $f$ with one pole and one zero.

I heavily suspect Riemann-Roch is involved in this exercise, but I can't find a way to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were such a meromorphic function $f$, we could extend it to a holomorphic map $F: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ (the pole mapped to the infinity point). This map clearly has degree $1$, and it is surjective by the irreducibility of the projective line. Therefore, it is an isomorphism. This is a contradiction, because the projective line has genus $0$ and the smooth plane cubic $C$ has genus $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain me what's going on in Riemann-Roch?

I have

$p=q$ $\to$ $l(0) - l(K) = 0 -1 +1$, therefore $l(0)=l(K)$
and
$p\neq q$ $\to$ $l(p-q) - l(K-p+q) = 0$. 
I thought since $l(0) = 1$ (constants) this implied $l(K)=1$, but since $l(p-q)$ should equal $0$ isn't $l(K-p+q)$ also $0$ ??

Comment: I mean, maybe the contradiction can't be derived from Riemann-Roch after all. Is that the case or I'm wrong about something?